Hiding posts from main page/archive but not RSS feed
I'm trying to hide certain posts (either by ID or category) from my site's main post list, archive post list, and the custom search feature, -but- I need those posts to still show up in RSS feed.
I've tried multiple approaches from articles/ChatGPT, but none have worked to hide the posts from the above locations.  I'm stumped.  It seems as if the add_action on pre_get_posts is just not working for some reason, but I'm not sure why.
Below are a few of the example code snippets I've tried in functions.php:
function myFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_feed) {
        $query->set('cat','-1'); //Don't forget to change the category ID
    }
return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','myFilter');

function exclude_posts_from_homepage($query) {
    if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        // Replace with the IDs of the posts you want to exclude from the homepage
        $exclude_posts = array(2324,2325,2327); // Replace with actual post IDs
        
        // Exclude posts from the homepage
        $query->set('post__not_in', $exclude_posts);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_posts_from_homepage', 1);


is there a particular pattern that makes those 3 categories similar that means you want to hide them? Parameters such as post__not_in and other NOT or __not_in exclusions are expensive, sometimes in the extreme, the database isn't optimised for those kinds of queries and they sometimes involve copying the entire table into memory at great cost. It can be much faster to ask it for posts in every single category except the ones you want to hide, than it is to ask for everything but those 3 categories

I have a post with a large table in it.  When this post gets added to RSS, Mailchimp sends it out by email, but it is jumbled due to the table size.  So my workaround was to have a 2nd copy of the post & table with just 2 columns that formats in the email properly when added to RSS.  But I have to be able to hide that 2nd copy from viewing, and no method I've tried seems to be working.

ah so this is an X Y problem, would it not be easier (and faster) to ask about the original problem rather than asking how to fix your proposed solution?

No, not an XY problem.  I asked about the original problem in other forums, but didn't find a good solution that was technically feasible for me to implement.  I identified a solution that was, above, except for some reason the code is not functioning properly.  I thought stackexchange would be a good place to seek help on this very specific technical issue.

I mean that in the sense that X is the mailchimp problem, and Y is hiding the posts with the big tables that cause Mailchimp to mess up, but the code you've tried that implements Y hasn't worked, hence the question. What if there was a solution where you did not need additional posts? I can think of several approaches, including ones that let you have both tables in the same post. These would solve your problems but they would not answer this question

I've posted the broader question at the following link if you have any interest in contributing the knowledge you've stated you have...
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/425837/getting-table-to-format-properly-in-rss-feed-emails

I've closed this as a duplicate of the new question, you could have edited the question instead of creating a new one.
